# How to increase the number of features returned by an ArcGIS Online feature service

Tags: arcgis-online

When uploading a feature layer to ArcGIS Online, and then accessing it via ArcGIS Online's REST API, there is a limit of 1000 features returned.

Is it possible to increase the limit and return more than 1000 features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workflow is outlined here at [HowTo:  Update the maximum record count for feature services in ArcGIS Online](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/44060).

> - Log in to www.arcgis.com with administrator credentials
> - Click My Content, and navigate to the intended feature service
> - Open the feature service.  In the item details page of the feature service, click the hyperlink under 'Layers'. The ArcGIS REST Services 
>     Directory page opens
> - Modify the URL by appending 'admin' to the end of the URL and deleting the rest of the URL to the service: http://services.arcgis.com/xxxx/ArcGIS/admin
> - Click Enter to access the new page
> - Click Services and find the intended service. Click the service name. The URL becomes:
>     http://services.arcgis.com/xxxx/ArcGIS/admin/services/states.FeatureServer
> - Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click Update Definition
> - Change the value of the 'lastEditDate' key to null.
> - Search for the maxRecordCount parameter
> - Change all the default values of 1000 to the number of desired features records to display
> - Click Update Service Definition
> - Go back to the 'My Content' page and open  the feature service in a new web map. All features beyond 1000 are now included and displayed
>     as desired.

Comment: I'm finding that the second `maxRecordCount` value isn't being persisted after hitting Update Service Definition - I'll follow it up with Esri tech support

Comment: I can vouch this process works for me.  Let me know if support have trouble with the ticket.

Comment: @Simon my instance of ArcGIS Online is currently a trial - when I tried it on a paid instance it worked as expected. Thanks

Comment: Strange limitation to put on a trial account.  Good to know.